# CSS to make both fb like and twitter share in one line

Tags: html, css

```
<div style="float: left"; class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>

<a style="float: right"; href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="" data-lang="ko">트윗하기</a>

<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Is my code,

It's a fb like button and twitter share icon/button. I wish these to be next to each other, but they always go on each line.

How can i solve this? It's like theres an `display: block;` as default on both

As you can see in the above code i tried float: left and float: right, but without any success

Comment: Is this using WordPress or another CMS that is generating this code through a plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the Twitter IFrame in a div container. Float the div container and reduce the width of the Twitter IFrame to about 70px or so. I tested those 2 changes on the website in Firebug, and it seemed to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

DIV is a block-level element and Anchor (A) is an inline element.  Either you can set `A` to be block-level (`display: block`) or wrap the Anchor within another DIV and float the container DIV.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the widths of the iframes. FB's is 450px, and twitters is 139px.